# How to fix query for Window Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've this below update query when I'm trying to execute this getting below error. Is there any way we can fix that?

Error Message:

```
Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 41
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.
```

Completion time: 2021-12-22T17:56:29.7517046+05:30

```
        update EmpPFContributionTest 
    Set EmpContbtnWithoutTax = 
    (
            case when sum(isnull(epf.emp_contribution,0)) over(partition by epf.emp_no, epf.FinancialYear order by (epf.pcm_year * 100 + pcm_month)) + sum(isnull(epf.vpf,0)) over(partition by epf.emp_no, epf.FinancialYear order by (epf.pcm_year * 100 + epf.pcm_month)) < 3000 
                then sum(isnull(epf.emp_contribution,0)) over(partition by epf.emp_no, epf.FinancialYear order by (epf.pcm_year * 100 + pcm_month)) + sum(isnull(epf.vpf,0)) over(partition by epf.emp_no, epf.FinancialYear order by (epf.pcm_year * 100 + epf.pcm_month))
           else null
           end
    )
    from EmpPFContributionTest epf
```

Comment: You'll need to use an updatable CTE or subquery. Though storing aggregated values in a table is generally a bad idea; you'll constantly be chances your tail as you need to update lots of rows every time you `UPDATE` or `INSERT` a single one. A `VIEW` would be a better option.

Comment: Effectively the same question as your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70441840/need-to-update-column-from-derived-column-of-select-statement) which you marked as answered but you then replied you implemented a view.

Comment: It looks like the solution SQLPro has given is effective same as one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442624/2029983) too. I don't see why this is a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a subquery like :

```
WITH 
T AS 
(
SELECT CASE
            WHEN SUM(ISNULL(epf.emp_contribution, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY epf.emp_no, 
                                                                        epf.FinancialYear
                  ORDER BY(epf.pcm_year * 100 + pcm_month)) + SUM(ISNULL(epf.vpf, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY epf.emp_no, 
                                                                                                      epf.FinancialYear
                  ORDER BY(epf.pcm_year * 100 + epf.pcm_month)) < 3000
            THEN SUM(ISNULL(epf.emp_contribution, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY epf.emp_no, 
                                                                        epf.FinancialYear
                  ORDER BY(epf.pcm_year * 100 + pcm_month)) + SUM(ISNULL(epf.vpf, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY epf.emp_no, 
                                                                                                      epf.FinancialYear
                  ORDER BY(epf.pcm_year * 100 + epf.pcm_month))
            ELSE NULL
         END AS CALC
FROM EmpPFContributionTest epf
)
UPDATE epf
SET    EmpContbtnWithoutTax = CALC
FROM   T
       JOIN epf ON ???
```

Comment: No need for the join, you can update `T` directly